# small tag not works with input tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

The coding is,

```
<input type="tel" required #phone=ngModel pattern='^\d{10}$' [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': !phone.valid}" name="phone" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userModel.phone">
  <small [class.d-none]=”phone.valid || phone.untouched”>Phone number is required and must be ten digits</small>
```

The output console gives,

```
compiler.js:2427 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token Lexer Error: Unexpected character [”] at column 1 in expression [”phone.valid] at column 2 in [”phone.valid] in ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@58:9 ("-invalid': !phone.valid}" name="phone" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userModel.phone">
  <small [ERROR ->][class.d-none]=”phone.valid || phone.untouched”>Phone number is required and must be ten digits</smal"):
```

I used double single quotes as '' instead of double quotes as ", it gives error message as,

Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "small". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("ll [class.d-none]=''phone.valid || phone.untouched''>Phone number is required and must be ten digits[ERROR ->]

Comment: Try replacing `”` with `"`.

Comment: `Unexpected character [”]`

Comment: I used double single quotes as '', it gives error message as, Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "small". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("ll [class.d-none]=''phone.valid || phone.untouched''>Phone number is required and must be ten digits[ERROR ->]</small>

Comment: *I used double single quotes as''* That's not what the error indicates. It says that it has encountered the single **”** character. You are most-likely using a text editor to write your code that uses font formatting. Use an editor that does not apply formatting to characters.

Comment: I used ", and got output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the wrong quotes:

```
[class.d-none]=”phone.valid || phone.untouched”
```

Should be instead:

```
[class.d-none]="phone.valid || phone.untouched"
```

Comment: What is that '' symbol, I used double single quotes as '', it gives error message as, Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Unexpected closing tag "small". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see w3.org/TR/html5/… ("ll [class.d-none]=''phone.valid || phone.untouched''>Phone number is required and must be ten digits[ERROR ->]</small>

Comment: You advanced to the next error. Maybe you bother reading the error message? Would already have helped you in the first place. `It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. ` Post the whole snippet.

Comment: I just copied your code and pasted it works, but what is this symbol " and how to type this symbol using keyboard,

Comment: @David Really? It's a double-quote without any formatting. Also known as a straight-quote. Press **SHIFT** and the key just to the left of **SHIFT**. But, as I said earlier, use an editor that doesn't apply font formatting to your code, otherwise you'll get the smart quotes (**“”**) that caused the problem in the first place.

Comment: You probably need another editor or IDE. You may try Sublime Text, which is free to evaluate.

Comment: Or, [NotePad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), or [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), or [Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/), all of which are free.

Comment: I used the straight-qutote ", and got output.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<small [class.d-none]=”phone.valid || phone.untouched”>Phone number is required and must be ten digits</small>
```

With:

```
<small [class.d-none]="phone.valid || phone.untouched">Phone number is required and must be ten digits</small>
```

Comment: What is that '' symbol, I used double single quotes as '', it gives error message as, Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Unexpected closing tag "small". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see w3.org/TR/html5/… ("ll [class.d-none]=''phone.valid || phone.untouched''>Phone number is required and must be ten digits[ERROR ->]</small>

Comment: I just copied your code and pasted it works, but how to type this symbol " using keyboard,